# Bold symbol in math mode: \boldsymbol + \mathrm don't work

Tags: amsmath, bold, boldmath

I am writing an article with given LaTeX template. Usually, when I want to type vector as bold non-italic letter, I use command

```
\boldsymbol{ \mathrm{ \Phi} }
```

which works perfectly with basic `amsmath` included. This does not work, however, for provided template. `\boldsymbol` command gets negleted. I know I can use different approaches, such as `\mathbf` or `\bm`, but I would like to know what causes such behaviour. In case it was useful, I present code of the template:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{sth}[2016/04/21]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}} 
\ProcessOptions
\LoadClass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}% <-------- CHANGE HERE for the global margins
\usepackage{mathptmx} % for Times

\renewenvironment{maketitle}{
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{0mm}% <---------- CHANGE HERE
    \setlength{\topmargin}{0mm}
    \vspace{7mm}\hspace{-5mm}\@author\vspace{11.25mm}
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
    \normalfont 
    \fontsize{20}{22.65}
    \selectfont
    \begin{center}
    \@title\relax\end{center}\vspace{-6.45mm}
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
    \normalfont 
    \fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont\thispagestyle{firstpage}}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewenvironment{abstract}
{\small
    \begin{center}
    \end{center}
    \list{}{%
        \setlength{\leftmargin}{40mm}% <---------- CHANGE HERE
        \setlength{\rightmargin}{0mm}%
        \setstretch{1}
    }%
    \fontsize{10}{4mm}
    \selectfont
    \item\relax\vspace{-5mm}}
{\endlist}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\fontsize{14}{5mm}\arabic{section}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection\fontsize{14}{5mm}\arabic{subsection}.}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection\fontsize{14}{5mm}\arabic{subsubsection}.}

\usepackage{sectsty}

\sectionfont{
    \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{phv} % Arial
    \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{phv} % Arial 
    \fontsize{14}{5mm}\selectfont}

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}
\normalfont 
\fontsize{12}{13.6}\selectfont
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\setlength{\parindent}{5mm}
\setlength{\parskip}{5.65pt}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titlespacing*{\section}{-7pt}{19.8pt}{1.4pt}
\usepackage{authblk}
\renewcommand\Authfont{\fontsize{12}{14}\selectfont}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\@seccntformat}[1]{\csname the#1\endcsname\hspace{4pt}}
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{#1.}
\makeatother
\setstretch{1}
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{6mm plus 3pt minus 2pt}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{1.5mm plus 3pt minus 2pt}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,labelfont=footnotesize]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \rhead{Header}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Comment: (1) Please always post a complete, compilable, [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) which we can copy, paste, and compile to reproduce your problem.  (2) `\boldsymbol` is defined by the `amsmath` package, so if you don't load that, `\boldsymbol` will not be available.

Comment: mathptmx is a very basic and old emulation of times for math and does not provide bold fonts.

Comment: It's been a while, but this actually has done the trick! If you posted your answer, I would gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

`\mathrm{}` is useless in your example.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath} %for \boldsymbol

\begin{document}

Normal Phi: $\Phi$

Bold Phi: $\boldsymbol\Phi$

\end{document}
```

[image]